# How to manage NSUserdefaults values for image and textview?

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one applciation.In that application i used the both imageview and textview.And iam used the NSUserdefaults for storing the imageview image value and textview text value.But when iam going to another page and coming to main page only imageview image data will be available in nsuserdefaults,textview text data is not avialable.So please tell me how to get the textview text data also by using nsuserdefaults

Comment: hey You can store image name and for your text view you have to store string in nsuserdefault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your Key for spelling mistakes. By the way, just for reference,

Methods of saving images to NSUserDefaults:

Number 1: Saving and retrieving image directly:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *imageData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:imageView.image];
[userDefaults setObject:imageData forKey:@"Image"];

//Retrieving
UIImage *image = (UIImage*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"Image"]];
```

Number 2: Saving the image in documents directory and saving its path in NSUserDefaults:

```
//Saving
//Obtain the path for Documents Directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];      

//Append Image name to the path
NSString *imagePath = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image"] retain];  

//Creating a file at this path
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
BOOL ok = [fileManager createFileAtPath:dataFilePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
if (!ok) {
    NSLog(@"Error creating file %@", dataFilePath);
} 
else {
    //Writing image to the created file
    NSFileHandle *myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:imagePath];

    [myFileHandle writeData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0)];
    [myFileHandle closeFile];
}

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (userDefaults) {

    [userDefaults setObject:imagePath forKey:@"ImagePath"];

}

//Retrieving
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *imagePath = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"ImagePath"];
NSFileHandle* fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:dataFilePath];
UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[fileHandle readDataToEndOfFile]];
```

Method of saving text to NSUserDefaults:

```
//Saving
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setValue:textView.text forKey:@"Text"];

//Retrieving
textView.text = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"Text"];
```

Comment: text data is not coming when we came from another view

Comment: u need to acces it. how are you accessing it and assigning it to the textView.text?

Comment: if(textView.tag==0)
 {
 [data setValue:textView.text forKey:@"keyToBvrgText"];
  
 }

Comment: Like this i take the data from textview

Comment: if([[data stringForKey:@"keyToBvrgText"] isEqualToString:@""])
   {
  txtView.text=@"I had";
   }
  else
  {
  txtView.text=[data valueForKey:@"keyToBvrgText"];
  }

Comment: NSLog the NSUserDefaults after saving to see if it has actually been saved. If not try changing the textView's tag to something other than 0

Comment: may be. just try putting log statements and discover your problem